# Sticky Nav using Waypoints resize issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, jquery-waypoints

I am in the process of developing a site for my class project and I am using waypoints to implement a sticky navigation. The navigation upon page load is positioned at the bottom of the ViewPort and has you scroll up once waypoints detects the nav bar has hit the top of the viewport it applies a class of "nav-is-sticky" When scrolling back up waypoints detects again and puts it back in the correct place.

My problem happens with window resizing I know what is wrong I just cant figure out a solution even though it is staring me in the face. If you are scrolled down the page and the navigation has been "stuck" to the top of the viewport and then you resize the window waypoints function runs again and since navigation is stuck to top of viewport it triggers the hit and puts it back up in its original position.

problem can be seen here, scroll down so hero image is out of view and resize window. 
http://www.digitaldripmedia.com/web_campaign_project

Here is the css

```
.nav-global-bar {
position: absolute;
background-color: $dark-gray;
height: 4.25em;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
}
.nav-is-sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

and here is the jquery

```
    var windowH = $(window).height();
     var navH = $('nav').height();





function navPos() {
   windowH = $(window).height();
   navH = $('nav').height();
    var nav = $('nav');

   if (!nav.hasClass('nav-is-sticky')) {
      // positions nav bar at bottom of viewport
     nav.css({
       top: windowH - navH
     });
   }

   nav.waypoint(function(direction) {
     if (direction == 'down') {
       // if nav bar hits top of viewport apply nav is stick class
       nav.addClass('nav-is-sticky');
       $('.nav-is-sticky').css({
         top: 0
       });
     } else if (direction == 'up') {
       //remove nav is sticky class when scrolling back up and put back to original spot
       nav.removeClass('nav-is-sticky');
       if (!nav.hasClass('nav-is-sticky')) {
         nav.css({
           top: windowH - navH
         });
       }
     }
   });
 }

 navPos();

 $(window).resize(function() {
  if(!$('nav').hasClass('nav-is-sticky')) {
  navPos();
}
 });
```

any help is much appreciated as well as any ways of doing this task in a better cleaner manner I am still new to jquery thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to pin a waypoint to a moving object is almost certainly going to give you undesired results - you can get the effect you're after by calling the `.waypoint()` function on your `main` element instead of on the nav. That will ensure the waypoint only triggers when you're actually at that scroll level on the page.

Also, you're calling the waypoint() function inside your navPos one, but it doesn't need to be reinitialized over and over like that; just move the initial .waypoint() call outside and have it happen on page load.

Edit: I tested this a little more and my initial solution may not actually be the effect you wanted; if it isn't, take a look at the [waypoints sticky-positioning shortcut](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/); might give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much that was absolutely driving me crazy and the whole time all I had to do was trigger the waypoint on main. Jack is there a reason why the waypoint on the moving object gives undesired results? Is it because the position absolute taking it out of the flow?

Comment: That's the heart of it, yes. Basically you're both shifting where on the page that element falls relative to the viewport, and responding to that position - by shifting the element again. So it becomes sort of self-interfering.